# Symfony Adding and Dealing With Custom Form Fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I am using Symfony with propel to generate a form called BaseMeetingMeetingsForm.

In MeetingMeetingsForm.class.php I have the following configure method:

```
public function configure() {
    $this->useFields(array('name', 'group_id', 'location', 'start', 'length'));

    $this->widgetSchema['invited'] = new myWidgetFormTokenAutocompleter(array("url"=>"/user/json"));
}
```

In MeetingMeetings.php my save method is simply:

```
  public function save(PropelPDO $con = null) {
    $this->setOwnerId(Meeting::getUserId());

    return parent::save($con);
  }
```

However propel doesn't know  about my custom field and as such doesn't do anything with it. Where and how to I put in a special section that can deal with this form field, please be aware it is not just a simple save to database, I need to deal with the input specially before it is input.

Thanks for your time and advice,

Comment: Please share the code where you read/process the form data.

Comment: There is none, symfony does it all somewhere, unless you know where?

Comment: Okay, then that is the part you're missing. You need to process form data on your own if the standard processing by the abstraction does not everything you would love to get automatically. See http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/10 and scroll down for *The Form Action*. It should have the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a validator (and/or create your own). The validator `clean()` method returns the value that needs to be persisted.

In Doctrine (I don't know Propel) the form then calls the `doUpdateObject()` on the form, which in turns calls the `fromArray($arr)` function on the model.

So if it's already a property on your model you'll only need to create the validator. If it's a more complex widget, you'll need to add some logic to the form.